# $HK = G$ and $H \cap K = 1 \iff a \in G$ written uniquely in the form $a = hk$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is a question from Rotman's *Introduction to the Theory of Groups* (2.69):

> If $H, K \lhd G$, then $HK = G$ and $H \cap K = 1$ if and only if every element $g \in G$ can be written uniquely in the form $g = hk$ for some $h \in H$ and $k \in K$.

I've shown the forward ($\implies$) direction, but am getting hung up on the other direction.  Suppose every element $g \in G$can be written uniquely in the form $g = hk$ for some $h \in H$ and $k \in K$.  It is clear then that $G = HK$.

I am stuck on showing $H \cap K = 1$. I couldn't see a direct approach, so instead I said that there is a bijection from $G$ to $H \times K$ defined by $g = hk \mapsto (h, k)$.  Then $|G| = |H||K|$, and so $|G| = |HK| = \frac{|H||K|}{|H \cap K|} = \frac{|G|}{|H \cap K|}$.  I have some reservations about this idea though.  What if $G$ is infinite?  Then my approach is unclear.  I also haven't used that $H$ and $K$ are normal anywhere, which makes me suspicious. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $|H\cap K|>1$, then you can find $x\in H\cap K$ with $x\neq e$. Then, we would have $e=e\cdot e$ and $e=x\cdot x^{-1}$, this are two distinct ways of writing $e$, a contradiction.

Comment: I knew it was something obvious.  Thank you.  So where is normality of $H$ and $K$ being used in this claim?  Do we need it to say $HK$ is a subgroup?

Comment: Yes. You need it for that reason.

Comment: The second statement of the theorem implies that $HK = G$, so it is a subgroup. So normality is not required.

Comment: @Arthur thats right. As a set $HK=G$, so $HK$ has a group structure. In general for proper subgroups you do need it though.

Comment: so for that other direction you dont use normality.